# ACL doesn't always get inherited

Tags: solaris, acl

Solaris platform.
Why is it that "sometimes" a file copied into a directory that has a default ACL attribute does not inherit that ACL? Other times it does.

Comment: This is probably a good question to have on here but how it's phrased is too broad. Can you give us an example of when it's not applying the default ACL when you think it should be? If we don't know what you're doing we can't explain why it's working that way.

Comment: Alright, I copy 10 files with the same basis permissions into a directory with a default ACL. 8 of them inherit the ACL and 2 do not.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show: 1) The full command you're using to copy 2) the output of `getfacl` of the directory you're copying them into and 3) a `getfacl` on one or two of each group (those that inherited and those that did not inherit).